can't install gmdb2 using macports on Sonoma
I can't install gmdb2 using MacPorts on Sonoma 14.4.1
I try
aladino@pc-23 ~ % sudo port install gmdb2  

but I get
--->  Computing dependencies for gmdb2
The following dependencies will be installed:  yelp
Continue? [Y/n]: y
--->  Fetching archive for yelp
--->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/yelp
--->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://fra.de.packages.macports.org/yelp
--->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/yelp
--->  Building yelp
Error: Failed to build yelp: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.
Error: Processing of port gmdb2 failed

Here's the content of the mentioned log file
version:1
:debug:main Starting logging for yelp @3.38.3_4
:debug:sysinfo macOS 14.4.1 (darwin/23.4.0) arch arm
:debug:sysinfo MacPorts 2.9.3
:debug:sysinfo Xcode none, CLT 15.3.0.0.1.1708646388
:debug:sysinfo SDK 14
:debug:sysinfo MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 14.0
:debug:main dropping privileges: euid changed to 502, egid changed to 501.
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (yelp)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch archivefetch phase started at Tue May  7 17:33:29 WEST 2024
:msg:archivefetch --->  Fetching archive for yelp
:debug:archivefetch Executing org.macports.archivefetch (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 0/0
:debug:archivefetch chowned /opt/local/var/macports/incoming to macports
:debug:archivefetch euid/egid changed to: 502/501
:info:archivefetch --->  yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/incoming/verified
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/yelp
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://fra.de.packages.macports.org/yelp
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:msg:archivefetch --->  Attempting to fetch yelp-3.38.3_4.darwin_23.arm64.tbz2 from https://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/yelp
:debug:archivefetch Fetching archive failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.extract (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.patch (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:archivefetch Skipping completed org.macports.configure (yelp)
:debug:archivefetch Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Tue May  7 17:33:30 WEST 2024
:notice:build --->  Building yelp
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (yelp)
:debug:build Environment: 
:debug:build CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
:debug:build CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
:debug:build CPATH='/opt/local/include'
:debug:build DEVELOPER_DIR='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
:debug:build LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
:debug:build MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='14.0'
:debug:build SDKROOT='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk'
:info:build Executing:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3" && /usr/bin/make -j10 -w all 
:debug:build system:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3" && /usr/bin/make -j10 -w all 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
:info:build make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build Making all in po
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3/po'
:info:build make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3/po'
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-bookmarks.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-bookmarks.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-bookmarks.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-bookmarks.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-bookmarks.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-debug.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-debug.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-debug.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-debug.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-debug.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-error.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-error.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-error.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-error.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-error.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-docbook-document.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-docbook-document.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-docbook-document.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-docbook-document.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-docbook-document.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-document.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-document.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-document.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-document.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-document.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-help-list.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-help-list.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-help-list.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-help-list.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-help-list.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-document.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-info-document.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-document.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-info-document.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-info-document.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-parser.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-info-parser.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-parser.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-info-parser.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-info-parser.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-magic-decompressor.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-magic-decompressor.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-magic-decompressor.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-magic-decompressor.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-magic-decompressor.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DDATADIR=\""/opt/local/share"\" -DYELP_ICON_PATH=\"/opt/local/share/yelp-xsl/icons\" -DYELP_WEB_EXTENSIONS_DIR=\""/opt/local/lib/yelp/"web-extensions\" -I./libyelp -I/opt/local/include -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/opt/local/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/dbus-1.0 -I/opt/local/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0 -I/opt/local/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/fribidi -I/opt/local/include/harfbuzz -I/opt/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/opt/local/include/cairo -I/opt/local/include/pixman-1 -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -I/opt/local/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wno-deprecated-declarations -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -arch arm64 -g -MT libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-mallard-document.lo -MD -MP -MF libyelp/.deps/libyelp_la-yelp-mallard-document.Tpo -c -o libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-mallard-document.lo `test -f 'libyelp/yelp-mallard-document.c' || echo './'`libyelp/yelp-mallard-document.c
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-debug.lo] Error 63
:info:build make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-document.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-help-list.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-bookmarks.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-document.lo] Error 63
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-docbook-document.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-mallard-document.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-error.lo] Error 63
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-info-parser.lo] Error 63
:info:build libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, but the
:info:build libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.7.
:info:build libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6
:info:build libtool: and run autoconf again.
:info:build make[2]: *** [libyelp/libyelp_la-yelp-magic-decompressor.lo] Error 63
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/work/yelp-3.38.3" && /usr/bin/make -j10 -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build Failed to build yelp: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 49967 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
:debug:build     while executing
:debug:build "system {*}$notty {*}$callback {*}$nice $fullcmdstring"
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "command_exec -callback portprogress::target_progress_callback build"
:debug:build     (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 10)
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "$procedure $targetname"
:error:build See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_yelp/yelp/main.log for details.

But to me it seems I already have the right version of libtool
aladino@pc-23 ~ % glibtool --version
glibtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.7
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit, 1996

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

aladino@pc-23 ~ % 
aladino@pc-23 ~ % 
aladino@pc-23 ~ % 
aladino@pc-23 ~ % libtool -V
Apple Inc. version cctools-1010.6

anyone can help please?
thanks
